# Filling in Null rows of a dataset with LAG, OVER and undetermined amount of offset?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

everyone. First time I've posted here. I looked for some sticky threads that might tell me some "HEY DO THIS BEFORE YOU POST FOR THE FIRST TIME" info, but I may have missed it. So, here's the question:

I'm working on building out a dataset for an analysis, and I'm trying to fill in some null rows. I don't know if it's the best way, but I think I need to LAG OVER PARTITION BY this dataset. Here's an example of the table:

[image: Table of Customer Bids]

My goal would be to have all of the *null* values in the **BidEnd** field filled with the most recent cell above it. So, rows 1-4 would all be filled with 2020-01-03. The end goal is to be able to label all the rows as valid or not. If the bid start occurred after the bid end, then it would not be valid. The dataset will need to do this with all customers and then with all bid_ids grouped under that customer.

I'd much prefer to use the code and an actual example, but I am not allowed to share that information, so I've tried to recreate the scenario as best as possible. Sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard SQL, you would use `lag(ignore nulls)`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(bidend ignore nulls) over (partition by customer2 order by row)
from t;
```

Although standard SQL, not all databases support the `ignore nulls` option on `lag()`.  That is why tagging your database is important.

Actually, it looks like you have one value per `customer2`/`bid_id` pair.  If that is true, you can use `max()`:

```
select t.*,
       max(bidend) over (partition by customer2, bid_id)
from t;
```

Comment: I came back to this question to accept the answer. Getting used to using the forum, so sorry for not doing so earlier.